# Network Connection Listener in Windows Mobile

Tags: windows-mobile, marmalade

We are using the [Marmalade SDK](http://www.madewithmarmalade.com/marmalade) for window's Mobile 6.5 development. 
In our application we are showing Status of Network Connection. Is there any listener available in the Marmalade SDK which can notify when Network Connection state is changes (i.e. It should notify when network connection gone and should again notify when network is connected again)?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try using s3eSocketGetInt(S£E_SOCKET_NETWORK_TYPE); that returns a s3eNetworkType that will return the available network.

```
S3E_NETWORK_TYPE_NONE = 0, 
S3E_NETWORK_TYPE_UNKNOWN = 1, 
S3E_NETWORK_TYPE_LAN = 2, 
S3E_NETWORK_TYPE_WLAN = 3, 
S3E_NETWORK_TYPE_GPRS = 4, 
S3E_NETWORK_TYPE_UMTS = 5, 
S3E_NETWORK_TYPE_EVDO = 6, 
S3E_NETWORK_TYPE_CDMA2000 = 7, 
S3E_NETWORK_TYPE_HSDPA = 8
```